# More accurate emulator, Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox doesn't seem to be yielding the same result when it comes to the rendered output with their emulators.

For example, Google Chrome seems to show rendering of iPhone X (375x812 in portrait mode, and with a device pixel ratio of 3) fonts very small.

According to my calculations, h1--which I set to 72px, seems to end up with font size 24px (that is 72 / 3, where 3 is the device pixel ratio). This doesn't happen with tablet (for example, iPad Pro, where the device pixel ratio is 2).

I expected the font size to be 72px / 2 = 36px on tablet, but it wasn't. It was rendered properly, as a device with a pixel ratio of 1 (desktop, for example).

Why is this happening with mobile or a device with a pixel ratio of 3 or above only? And, of course, this doesn't seem to be happening with Mozilla Firefox, where font size is rendered the same across all of these devices.

Which browser's rendering is correct in this case? Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox?

The screenshots are given below.

[Google Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1RNB.jpg)

[Mozilla Firefox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th0L4.jpg)

Comment: Hi! Please provide a [mcve] of your code - screenshots are not acceptable replacements for code when askin for help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nor Chrome or Firefox have an actual Simulator, the CSS engine behind is the same, however they emulate some things like touch input or display size. If you really want an actual Simulator you should look for a virtual device

Comment: okay, @TylerH. thank you

Answer (score 0):

include the meta tag like this.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

most people here downrate questions without knowing anything. they don't just go to the basics, these are the people who can't build a site without depending on a framework like bootstrap. there this won't be a problem coz it's already taken care of by experts.

for more details, refer [this excellent w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)